# Basic GUI program layout positioning

Tags: java, swing, awt, layout-manager

I have been trying to figure out how to properly layout my program for quite a while now. I basically have 5 JLabels, 5 JTextFields, and 6 JButtons, I need to align it as shown below.

I tried using a GridLayout but it make the JTextFields really thick, I tried different combinations of flow layout with mixed results. I was wondering if someone can guide me as to how I can get the below result?

Thanks in advance.

Here is my code as it stands now:

```
   public class MyClass extends JFrame{
        private JTextField item1;
        private JTextField item2;
        private JTextField item3;
        private JTextField item4;
        private JTextField item5;
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Enter number of items in this order:");
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Enter CD ID for Item #1:");
        JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Enter quantity for Item #1:");
        JLabel label4 = new JLabel("Item #1 info:");
        JLabel label5 = new JLabel("Order subtotal for 0 item(s):");
        private JButton button1 = new JButton("Process Item #1");
        private JButton button2 = new JButton("Confirm Item #1");
        private JButton button3 = new JButton("View Order");
        private JButton button4 = new JButton("Finish Order");
        private JButton button5 = new JButton("New Order");
        private JButton button6 = new JButton("Exit");
        private Scanner x;
        private int exitFlag = 0;
        public String[] idArray = new String[10];
        public String[] recordArray = new String[10];
        public String[] priceArray = new String[10];
        public int myNum=1;
        private JPanel jp = new JPanel();


        public void openFile(){
            try{
                x = new Scanner(new File("inventory.txt"));
                x.useDelimiter(",|" + System.getProperty("line.separator")); 
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Could not find file");
            }
        }
        public void readFile(){
            int i=0;
            while(x.hasNext()){
                idArray[i] = x.next();
                recordArray[i] = x.next();
                priceArray[i] = x.next();
                i++;
            }
        }
        public int itemNum(int num){
            return num+1;
        }
        public MyClass(){
            super("Matt's World of Music");
            jp.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));


            Box vertBox = Box.createVerticalBox();
            Box vertBox2 = Box.createVerticalBox();
            Box itemBox2 = Box.createHorizontalBox();

            item1 = new JTextField(40);
            item2 = new JTextField(40);
            item3 = new JTextField(40);
            item4 = new JTextField(40);
            item5 = new JTextField(40);


            vertBox.add(label1);
            vertBox.add(label2);
            vertBox.add(label3);
            vertBox.add(label4);
            vertBox.add(label5);
            jp.add(vertBox);
            vertBox2.add(item1);
            vertBox2.add(item2);
            vertBox2.add(item3);
            vertBox2.add(item4);
            vertBox2.add(item5);
            jp.add(vertBox2);


            itemBox2.add(button1);
            itemBox2.add(button2);
            itemBox2.add(button3);
            itemBox2.add(button4);
            itemBox2.add(button5);
            itemBox2.add(button6);
            jp.add(itemBox2);
            add(jp);


            button2.setEnabled(false);
            button3.setEnabled(false);
            button4.setEnabled(false);
            item4.setEditable(false);
            item5.setEditable(false);

            //Process Item
            button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                  MyClass obj = new MyClass();

                  button1.setEnabled(false);
                  button2.setEnabled(true);
                  item1.setEditable(false);

                  obj.openFile();
                  obj.readFile();

                  //start loop
                  for(int i=0; i < idArray.length; i++){
                      if(item2.getText().equals(obj.idArray[i])==true){
                          //set item4 text field to price id and other details
                          item4.setText(obj.idArray[i] + " " + obj.recordArray[i] + " $" + obj.priceArray[i].replaceAll("\\s",""));
                      }
                   }                  
                }
            });
            //Confirm Item
            button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                    if(myNum==Integer.parseInt(item1.getText())){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Item #" + (myNum) + " accepted");
                        button2.setEnabled(false);
                        button1.setText("Process Item");
                        button2.setText("Confirm Item");
                        button1.setEnabled(false);
                        button3.setEnabled(true);
                        button4.setEnabled(true);
                        item2.setText("");
                        item3.setText("");
                        label2.setText("");
                        label3.setText("");
                        item2.setEditable(false);
                        item3.setEditable(false);
                    }else{
                        //Execute when button is pressed
                        button1.setEnabled(true);
                        button2.setEnabled(false);
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Item #" + (myNum) + " accepted");
                        item2.setText("");
                        item3.setText("");
                        label2.setText("Enter CD ID for Item #" + (myNum+1) + ":");
                        label3.setText("Enter quantity for Item #" + (myNum+1) + ":");
                        label4.setText("Item #" + (myNum+1) + " info:");
                        myNum++;
                        button1.setText("Process item #" + (myNum));
                        button2.setText("Confirm item #" + (myNum));
                    }
                }
            });
            //View Order
            button3.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                    //Execute when button is pressed
                    System.out.println("View Order");
                }
            });
            //Finish Order
            button4.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                    //Execute when button is pressed
                    System.out.println("Finish Order");
                }
            });
            //New Order
            button5.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                   //Execute when button is pressed
                   System.out.println("New Order");
               }
            });
            //Quit
            button6.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

                   //exit program

               }
            }); 
        }      
}
```

Comment: you can try and see if a visual editor would help you http://code.google.com/p/visualswing4eclipse/      (for swing and eclipse), though i guess awt isnt swing.  sorry dont know that much about straight java gui development

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a simple `GridBagLayout` makes it look like in your screenshot:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MyClass extends JFrame {
    private final JTextField item1;
    private final JTextField item2;
    private final JTextField item3;
    private final JTextField item4;
    private final JTextField item5;
    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Enter number of items in this order:");
    JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Enter CD ID for Item #1:");
    JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Enter quantity for Item #1:");
    JLabel label4 = new JLabel("Item #1 info:");
    JLabel label5 = new JLabel("Order subtotal for 0 item(s):");
    private final JButton button1 = new JButton("Process Item #1");
    private final JButton button2 = new JButton("Confirm Item #1");
    private final JButton button3 = new JButton("View Order");
    private final JButton button4 = new JButton("Finish Order");
    private final JButton button5 = new JButton("New Order");
    private final JButton button6 = new JButton("Exit");
    private Scanner x;
    private final int exitFlag = 0;
    public String[] idArray = new String[10];
    public String[] recordArray = new String[10];
    public String[] priceArray = new String[10];
    public int myNum = 1;
    private final JPanel jp;

    public void openFile() {
        try {
            x = new Scanner(new File("inventory.txt"));
            x.useDelimiter(",|" + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Could not find file");
        }
    }

    public void readFile() {
        int i = 0;
        while (x.hasNext()) {
            idArray[i] = x.next();
            recordArray[i] = x.next();
            priceArray[i] = x.next();
            i++;
        }
    }

    public int itemNum(int num) {
        return num + 1;
    }

    public MyClass() {
        super("Matt's World of Music");

        jp = new JPanel();
        jp.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.BASELINE_TRAILING;

        // Box vertBox = Box.createVerticalBox();
        // Box vertBox2 = Box.createVerticalBox();
        // Box itemBox2 = Box.createHorizontalBox();

        item1 = new JTextField(40);
        item2 = new JTextField(40);
        item3 = new JTextField(40);
        item4 = new JTextField(40);
        item5 = new JTextField(40);

        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        jp.add(label1, c);

        c.gridy++;
        jp.add(label2, c);

        c.gridy++;
        jp.add(label3, c);

        c.gridy++;
        jp.add(label4, c);

        c.gridy++;
        jp.add(label5, c);

        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 0;
        jp.add(item1, c);

        c.gridy++;
        jp.add(item2, c);

        c.gridy++;
        jp.add(item3, c);

        c.gridy++;
        jp.add(item4, c);

        c.gridy++;
        jp.add(item5, c);

        JPanel btnPan = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        btnPan.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 0, 0, 0));

        btnPan.add(button1);
        btnPan.add(button2);
        btnPan.add(button3);
        btnPan.add(button4);
        btnPan.add(button5);
        btnPan.add(button6);

        c.gridwidth = 2;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy++;
        jp.add(btnPan, c);
        add(jp);

        button2.setEnabled(false);
        button3.setEnabled(false);
        button4.setEnabled(false);
        item4.setEditable(false);
        item5.setEditable(false);

        // Process Item
        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                MyClass obj = new MyClass();

                button1.setEnabled(false);
                button2.setEnabled(true);
                item1.setEditable(false);

                obj.openFile();
                obj.readFile();

                // start loop
                for (int i = 0; i < idArray.length; i++) {
                    if (item2.getText().equals(obj.idArray[i]) == true) {
                        // set item4 text field to price id and other details
                        item4.setText(obj.idArray[i] + " " + obj.recordArray[i] + " $"
                                + obj.priceArray[i].replaceAll("\\s", ""));
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        // Confirm Item
        button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (myNum == Integer.parseInt(item1.getText())) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Item #" + (myNum) + " accepted");
                    button2.setEnabled(false);
                    button1.setText("Process Item");
                    button2.setText("Confirm Item");
                    button1.setEnabled(false);
                    button3.setEnabled(true);
                    button4.setEnabled(true);
                    item2.setText("");
                    item3.setText("");
                    label2.setText("");
                    label3.setText("");
                    item2.setEditable(false);
                    item3.setEditable(false);
                } else {
                    // Execute when button is pressed
                    button1.setEnabled(true);
                    button2.setEnabled(false);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Item #" + (myNum) + " accepted");
                    item2.setText("");
                    item3.setText("");
                    label2.setText("Enter CD ID for Item #" + (myNum + 1) + ":");
                    label3.setText("Enter quantity for Item #" + (myNum + 1) + ":");
                    label4.setText("Item #" + (myNum + 1) + " info:");
                    myNum++;
                    button1.setText("Process item #" + (myNum));
                    button2.setText("Confirm item #" + (myNum));
                }
            }
        });
        // View Order
        button3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // Execute when button is pressed
                System.out.println("View Order");
            }
        });
        // Finish Order
        button4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // Execute when button is pressed
                System.out.println("Finish Order");
            }
        });
        // New Order
        button5.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // Execute when button is pressed
                System.out.println("New Order");
            }
        });
        // Quit
        button6.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                // exit program

            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                MyClass c = new MyClass();
                c.pack();
                c.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: thats not exactly what I was trying to do, but the closest answer yet, and looks clean. I appreciate the help. thank you:)

Comment: GridBagConstraints allow for the use of Insets, which will separate your components with some whitespace.  Also, you should use a new GridBagConstraint for each component.

Answer (score 2):

I would design it this way:

- the main panel would have a `BorderLayout` as the layout manager and contain 2 panels: one in the center and one on the south
- the panel in the center could have a `GridBagLayout` and contain the labels and the text fields
- the panel on the south could have a `FlowLayout` or a `BoxLayout` and include the buttons

Answer (score 2):

As a single layout, you might look to use `GroupLayout` or `GridBagLayout`.  I would probably do it as a nested layout.

- A `BorderLayout` for the outer container.
- A `GridLayout` of text fields in `LINE_END`.
- A `GridLayout` of labels in the `CENTER`.
- A `FlowLayout` for the buttons at `PAGE_END`.

If any of the text fields are larger than needed, wrap them in a `new JPanel(new FlowLayout())`  - the panel will fill the parent location, while allowing the text filed to shrink to whatever size it needs to be.

---

Of course that is ignoring the plethora of excellent 3rd party layouts such as `FormLayout`, `MigLayout`..